# WatchKit adding margin to Label

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

Is there a way to add a margin / padding to a WKInterfaceLabel in Watchkit?
Using UIEdgeInsets doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't WatchKit use WKInterfaceLabel?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should create a WKInterfaceGroup and add the WKInterfaceLabel inside the group. You can manage the margin/padding using that group.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

In your storyboard add your WKInterfaceLabel to a WKInterfaceGroup.  Then in the properties for the group set the insets to custom.  You can change the top, left, bottom, and right insets for the group.

[image]